I need to make run a module from button click, and I do not the code to put in button click in VB.Net?
This module create a database I need a statement to make it run from button click.
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Define your connection string (update this based on your server and database)
        Dim connectionString As String = ("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        ' Define the SQL command to create a new table
        Dim createTableQuery As String = "
        CREATE TABLE Employees (
            EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
            FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
            LastName NVARCHAR(50),
            BirthDate DATE
        )"
        ' Create and open a connection to SQL Express
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Try
                ' Open the connection
                connection.Open()
                ' Create a command to execute the SQL query
                Using command As New SqlCommand(createTableQuery, connection)
                    ' Execute the command
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Console.WriteLine("Table 'Employees' created successfully.")
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Handle any errors that may have occurred
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            Finally
                ' Close the connection
                connection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
        ' Pause the console so you can see the result (only if you're using a Console App)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

